# Cany anyone name this lightbox?

Tags: gallery

I'm new to the forums and hoping to find an answer to the following question:

Go to this website: http://www.indochino.com/product/gray-glen-plaid-suit
Click on the thumbnails

Can anyone identify this lightbox?
Is it a plugin or custom?
Any idea if it can be used with Wordpress?

Lastly, if nobody can identify this *exact* lightbox, do you know of anything similar?

Thanks!
_Michael

Answer (score 2):

Ist and custom gallery, i think. See in the source of `http://d3dgk6r8ca2pzn.cloudfront.net/js/gallery_1332969334.js`:

```
/** 
 * Image gallery used in product detail pages and customization pages
 * 
 * @module      Gallery
 * @author      Preet Jassi
 * @file        gallery.js 
 * @copyright   (c) 2011 Indochino Apparel Inc. 
 */
```

Use the yui lib from Yahoo: http://yuilibrary.com/

But maybe you find an gallery with yui, there have your requirements on the site, there have list all galleries with yui: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery cycle, move the buttons apart, keep the adjacent divs visible. So you get the same effect.